# ImportError: cannot import name 'combined_rule_sentence_segmenter'

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm facing error while importing "import en_ner_bc5cdr_md"

```
import scispacy
import spacy
from spacy import displacy
from collections import Counter
import en_core_web_sm
import en_ner_bc5cdr_md
import en_core_sci_sm
import en_core_sci_md
import en_ner_bionlp13cg_md
from scispacy.abbreviation import AbbreviationDetector
from scispacy.umls_linking import UmlsEntityLinker
from collections import OrderedDict
from pprint import pprint
```

Please help

Comment: You need to install the model: pip install en_ner_bc5cdr_md. See here: https://allenai.github.io/scispacy/

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the model first, try

`!pip install https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ai2-s2-scispacy/releases/v0.5.1/en_ner_bc5cdr_md-0.5.1.tar.gz`